Using a model to evaluate over or under-priced rental prices for the same apartments used in training
If I have a machine learning model which predicts the rental prices of apartments, can I use the model once complete to analyse the prediction for the same apartments I used to train the model so I can infer whether the model thinks they are over or underpriced? For example, let's say I have a dataset of 20,000 apartments. I train the model on 80% and then test on the remaining 20% until I am happy with the model's accuracy and performance. Can I then use that final model to make predictions for the 10,000 apartments to compare the model's predicted rental prices with the actual rental prices?
My aim is to determine whether the rental prices are above or below what would be expected.

It is bad practice to evaluate a model on the same data you trained it. Doing so will likely result in an overfit model showing over-optimistic results which will generalize poorly to new data.
As a silly counterexample, suppose your model simply memorizes each listing in the training data and just spits out the listed price. This model will be exactly correct for every training example, but will produce random output when applied to any new cases. Applying the model to the training data tells you nothing at all about how good the model actually is, or whether it tends to over- or under-estimate the true price in scenarios where it doesn't already know the answer.
Secondly, I'm not sure that this would really answer the question you're after - it would suppose that your model predictions are actually better than the real data. Suppose your model generally performs well, but predicts that one rental price "should be" much higher than the actual value. Does this mean that your model really is correct and that the rental is under-priced? Or does it mean that your model is just wrong, and that the rental is appropriately priced low for some reason your model didn't identify?
